# How I can remove all the events on a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a button in the backend as follow:

```
<?php
echo $this->myFormButton(
    'add_component_restriction',
    'Add',
    [
        'class'       => 'btn btn-default add_component_restriction',
        'type'        => 'button'
    ]
);
?>
```

This will generate the following HTML:

```
<button name="add_component_restriction" 
        id="add_component_restriction" 
        type="button" 
        value="Add" class="btn btn-default add_component_restriction" 
>Add</button>
```

The element could be rendered as view only meaning you can view it but you can't act on it and if so I should be able to remove all the actions on it.

I did know this can be done only on the DOM level using Javascript (maybe I am wrong) maybe using `.off()` or setting something like this `onclick="javascript: return false;"` on the element.

I don't know if make it `disabled` or `readonly` will do the job.

Is Javascript/jQuery the only way ? If there is another solution please let me know

Comment: *"you can view it but you can't act on it and if so I should be able to remove all the actions on it."* If you can't act on it, how would you be able to remove all the actions on it?

Comment: Do you want to remove all events? Or make the button unresponsive to click events?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I believe this is what I am looking for

Comment: a simple *"disabled"* will do it

Comment: @ReynierPM ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `disabled` attribute.

```
<?php
echo $this->myFormButton(
    'add_component_restriction',
    'Add',
    [
        'class'       => 'btn btn-default add_component_restriction',
        'type'        => 'button',
        'disabled'    => 'disabled'
    ]
);
?>
```

Comment: What about if I go and edit the page using Chrome Developers Tools? I would be able to submit the button no matter what, right?

Comment: Yes, there's no way to avoid this. But you can forbid any action issued by the button in the backend. @ReynierPM